# sprintf: printing a percent followed by 0-padded hex

Tags: c, printf

I thought I understand printf, but I guess not. I have:

```
char sTemp[100];
sprintf(sTemp, "%%%02x", (unsigned)c);
```

I think that c is an unsigned char and I think a linefeed, but for some reason, what I get coming out is

> 0x0.000000000000ap-1022

If I make the 'x' in the format string an 'X', then an 'X' appears in the output string.

Comment: can you show us a complete example? I cannot reproduce anything like that at all

Comment: As so often, the problem is not in the code that is shown, but in the code that is not shown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*I completely misinterpreted the results of my experiments in the first version of this answer; apologies all around.*

The result of that `sprintf()` call when c is `'\n'` is this string:

> "%0a"

I believe you are then doing:

```
printf(sTemp);
```

Which is the same as:

```
printf("%0a");
```

Which is a valid format string for hexadecimal float output. You aren't passing a float variable, however, so `printf()` pulls whatever happens to be on the stack nearby and uses that as the value to format.

Instead, do:

```
printf( "%s", sTemp );
```

and you should see your expected "%0a".

Note that clang, and probably other compilers, give you a warning when you use `printf(sTemp)`:

> so.c:9:12: warning: format string is not a string literal (potentially
>   insecure) [-Wformat-security]

Because of precisely this sort of thing: memory on the stack is accessed that wasn't supposed to be.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to make any difference, the compiler should already merge the two strings

Comment: However, it does make a difference in my test.

Comment: really? could you please give an example code that produces strange results

Comment: I used the OP's code, with `char c = '\n';` as the data to print -- and that's a critical part of what I now think is a clang bug.

Comment: so it really seems to be a clang issue. Using gcc, it hasn't been reproducable on three different linux machines

Comment: D'oh! Not a compiler bug after all, just total misinterpretation.

Comment: OK that's really good. Imagine a second +1 ... that's a really great mistake where people can learn from

Comment: I can't reproduce it with clang LLVM 5.1, using exactly the code above. My output is, as expected, `%0a`. Perhaps that was used as `printf(sTemp);` instead of `printf("%s\n", sTemp);`?

Comment: Ok, I see you had the same thought as I did. <g>

Comment: If I use `printf(sTemp);`, I get a warning (in the Xcode editor). I assume OP simply ignored it?

Comment: Yes, I *am* using the output string as the format string for another call. (I **knew** I'd be facepalming this when I got it). Thanks.

Comment: It's not going to be clear to everyone that this security warning could also explain the weird output. I've been writing in C for a quarter of a century, *I saw the same warning*, I should totally have known what was going on, and still leapt to the "compiler bug" interpretation, to my own embarrassment.

Comment: Oh and about the compiler, if this was my project, I'm pretty sure I would have figured it out for myself a long time ago, but I don't have control over the compiler flags or anything, so I didn't get the warnings I otherwise would have.